# Host Multiple Domains "Virtual Host" in a single Apache Server - MAMP

Tags: macos, apache-http-server, mamp

## Goal

I'm trying to host multiple domains "Virtual Host" in a single Apache Server - MAMP.

---

## Attempt

In my MAMP, I select port `8888`

---

I have this at the end of my `host file` on my Mac

**/etc/hosts**

```
127.0.0.1   l.ssc.com
127.0.0.1   l.pm.com
```

---

**httpd.conf**

I've added

```
<VirtualHost l.ssc.com:8888 >
    ServerName l.ssc.com
    DocumentRoot "/Applications/MAMP/htdocs/code/benu/ssc-portal/public/"
    <Directory "/Applications/MAMP/htdocs/code/benu/ssc-portal/public/">
        # Require all granted
        Options All
        AllowOverride All
        Order allow,deny
        Allow from all
        XSendFilePath "/Applications/MAMP/htdocs"
    </Directory>
</VirtualHost>


<VirtualHost l.pm.com:8888 >
    ServerName l.pm.com
    DocumentRoot "/Applications/MAMP/htdocs/code/biossantibodies/public/"
    <Directory "/Applications/MAMP/htdocs/code/biossantibodies/public/">
        # Require all granted
        Options All
        AllowOverride All
        Order allow,deny
        Allow from all
        XSendFilePath "/Applications/MAMP/htdocs"
    </Directory>
</VirtualHost>
```

and Reboot my MAMP.

---

**result**

After visiting both sites,

http://l.ssc.com:8888/

AND

http://l.pm.com:8888/

I kept seeing Same site loaded which is the first one that got declare in my **httpd.conf** file.

[image]

---

I expect to see my http://l.pm.com:8888/ to load the different document root.

---

## Question

**How would one go about and debug this ?**

---

I'm opening to any suggestions at this moment.

Any hints / suggestions / helps on this be will  be much appreciated !

Answer (score 0):

Here the steps I took to achieve this

## - Commented out the stock MAMP DOCUMENT_ROOT

**/Applications/MAMP/conf/apache/httpd.conf**

```
# MAMP DOCUMENT_ROOT !! Don't remove this line !!

# DocumentRoot "/Applications/MAMP/htdocs/code/benu/ssc-portal/public"
# <Directory "/Applications/MAMP/htdocs/code/benu/ssc-portal/public">
#     Options All
#     AllowOverride All
#     Order allow,deny
#     Allow from all
#     XSendFilePath "/Applications/MAMP/htdocs"
# </Directory>
```

**Make sure to include a vhost file, by uncomment the line below like so**

```
# Virtual hosts
Include /Applications/MAMP/conf/apache/extra/httpd-vhosts.conf
```

---

## - Add configs to vhost file

**/Applications/MAMP/conf/apache/extra/httpd-vhosts.conf**

```
NameVirtualHost *:8888

<VirtualHost *:8888 >
    ServerName l.ssc.com
    DocumentRoot "/Applications/MAMP/htdocs/code/benu/ssc-portal/public/"
    <Directory "/Applications/MAMP/htdocs/code/benu/ssc-portal/public/">
        # Require all granted
        Options All
        AllowOverride All
        Order allow,deny
        Allow from all
        XSendFilePath "/Applications/MAMP/htdocs"
    </Directory>
</VirtualHost>


<VirtualHost *:8888 >
    ServerName l.pm.com
    DocumentRoot "/Applications/MAMP/htdocs/code/biossantibodies/public/"
    <Directory "/Applications/MAMP/htdocs/code/biossantibodies/public/">
        # Require all granted
        Options All
        AllowOverride All
        Order allow,deny
        Allow from all
        XSendFilePath "/Applications/MAMP/htdocs"
    </Directory>
</VirtualHost>
```

---

## - Restart MAMP